Function.count returns 0 on a query that includes Join
I have documents such as
Category(type="category", catId = 1, name = "cat")

and Products with
Product(catId=1, type="product"), Product(catId=1, type="product")

Now I want to get list of all Categories (all their field) and the total number of products per category. The query runs and returns all categories correctly but the total number of products per category is 0. I am sure each category has a product(s) though.
val catAlias = "catAlias"
        val productAlias = "productAlias"

        val q =
            QueryBuilder
                .select(
                    SelectResult.expression(Function.count(Expression.property("$productAlias.catId").from(productAlias))).`as`("totalProducts"),
                    SelectResult.all().from(catAlias),
                    SelectResult.expression(Meta.id.from(catAlias)).`as`("metaId"),

                    )
                .from(
                    DataSource.database(readsDB).`as`(catAlias),
                )
                .join(
                    Join.leftJoin(DataSource.database(readsDB).`as`(productAlias))
                        .on(
                            Expression.property("$productAlias.type").equalTo(
                                Expression.string(
                                    "product",
                                ),
                            )
                                .and(
                                    Expression.property("$productAlias.catId")
                                        .equalTo(Expression.property("$catAlias.catId")),
                                ),
                        ),
                )
                .where(
                    Expression.property("$catAlias.type").from(catAlias)
                        .equalTo(Expression.string("category")),

                    ).groupBy(
                Expression.property("$catAlias.catId")
            )

What could be the error?

not sure if it is the right way but this fixed it:
            SelectResult.expression(Function.count(Expression.string("*"))).`as`("productsCount")


We are puzzled by this bit in the first SELECT line of your original query: .from(productAlias))).   What happens if you just delete that?
